# How to detect the foreground thread which is not closed(wpf)

Tags: wpf, multithreading

For a large scale wpf applications,,there are many threads. Maybe is it a socket thread. My Problem is how to detect the foreground thread which block my application to close! 
i change the application to consolo,so i can output the log! But when I close the UI window, the Consolo Win doesn't close, I don't konw why, i have released the Unmanaged resources which i used.
Has some tools can help me to detect? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads property (ProcessThreadCollection) checking for threads with IsBackground property == false; These are foreground threads, which will prevent Windows from closing the process while they are running. Calling Thread.Kill will force termination of a thread.